# Deadlock when logging of using Simple MAPI TEmail component

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, windbg, windows-server-2003, mapi

We are experiencing an intermittent deadlock using a freeware [MAPI/SMAPI](http://delphi.icm.edu.pl/ftp/d10free/temail2.htm) implementation. I doubt the implementation is at fault but perhaps changing the logon flags to MapiLogon or a configuration setting on Exchange could resolve this.

```
Result := MapiLogon(0, LogonProfile, LogonPassword, flLogonFlags, 0, @hSession);
```

**Added** *cudo's to @J*

The use of [Simple MAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296734(v=vs.85).aspx) altogether is discouraged. The proper action would be to start using Extended MAPI or the Outlook Object Model. While I agree with the statement, I have no influence whatsoever to make that happen.

A solution for the current setup or understanding why the deadlock might occur is still much apreciated.

**In short**

- Thread `0b60` calls `MapiLogof`
- During logof, it waits for thread `0894`
- Thread `0894` waits for Critical Section `036c`
- Critical Section `036c` is locked by thread `0b60`

**Deadlock**

the kernel dump shows following critical section being locked and owned by thread `b60`

```
    CritSec EMSMDB32!ScStatClose+17ac7 at 354650d0
    WaiterWoken        No
    LockCount          1
    RecursionCount     1
    OwningThread       b60
    EntryCount         0
    ContentionCount    1
    *** Locked
```

Thread's `0b60` call stack

*kernel thread object 88a53758*
*Note the `KeWaitForSingleObject` with parameter `87fc3c68` being thread `0894`*

```
    b8b4fcec 8093b2e4 87fc3c68 00000006 00000001 nt!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x346 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    b8b4fd50 8088b658 00000184 00000000 00000000 nt!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x9a (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    b8b4fd50 7c82845c 00000184 00000000 00000000 nt!KiSystemServicePostCall (FPO: [0,0] TrapFrame @ b8b4fd64)
    0012f618 7c827b79 77e61d06 00000184 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
    0012f61c 77e61d06 00000184 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
    0012f68c 77e61c75 00000184 ffffffff 00000000 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0xac (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    0012f6a0 3540fc13 00000184 ffffffff 02102150 kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    0012f6b4 3540a226 7c81a1a8 3540546f 02102108 EMSMDB32!XPProviderInit+0x58d5
    0012f6bc 3540546f 02102108 00db29c0 0012f6f0 EMSMDB32!MSProviderInit+0x16af6
    0012f6d0 3553ce40 02102108 35411e97 02102108 EMSMDB32!MSProviderInit+0x11d3f
    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 MSMAPI32!UlRelease+0xe
    /* Reconstructed from MAP file */
    0012f878  00422b81 21B81      mailrequestserver+0x22b81      0001:00021B70       MapiLogoff
    0012f894  00423dde 22DDE      mailrequestserver+0x23dde      0001:00022DB0       TEmail.Logoff
```

Thread's `0894` call stack is

*kernel thread object 87fc3c68*
*Note the `EMSMDB32!ScStatClose` call resulting in `RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection` with parameter `0000036c` being the critical section owned by thread `0b60`*

```
    0231ff80 7c83d0f7 0000036c 00000004 00000000 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0x1a3 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    0231ffa0 3544d394 354650d0 00000000 00000001 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0xa8 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    0231ff98 354650d0                            EMSMDB32!ScStatClose+0x17ac7
    0231ffa4 3544d394                            EMSMDB32!EcUnregisterPushNotification+0x12033
    0231ffa8 354650d0                            EMSMDB32!ScStatClose+0x17ac7
    0231ffb4 3544d114                            EMSMDB32!EcUnregisterPushNotification+0x11db3
```

**Question**

1. The call stack shows there's an `UnregisterPushNotifications` involved. Searching for push notifications, I can't find any reason why we would need that *(we just logon, send a mail and logof)* but, as this happens entirely in MAPI, I don't know how we can prevent the call from happening.
2. If the push notification can't be ignored/disabled somehow, any pointers to what else might cause/resolve this are very welcome.

**Some additional information**

1. Both threads belong to the same process
2. `MSMAPI32.dll` is version 10.0.6861.0
3. `EMSMDB32.dll` is version 10.0.6742.0

**Relevant code from SMapi.pas**

```
function MapiLogoff(lhSession  : LHANDLE;
                    ulUIParam  : ULONG;
                    flFlags    : ULONG;
                    ulReserved : ULONG): ULONG;

function MapiLogon(ulUIParam   : ULONG;
                   lpszName    : PChar;
                   lpszPassword: PChar;
                   flFlags     : ULONG;
                   ulReserved  : ULONG;
                   lplhSession : LPLHANDLE): ULONG;

function MapiSendMail(lhSession  : LHANDLE;
                      ulUIParam  : ULONG;
                      lpMessage  : lpMapiMessage;
                      flFlags    : ULONG;
                      ulReserved : ULONG): ULONG;

procedure InitializeSMAPI;
var
  OldErrorMode: Word;
  OSVersionInfo: TOSVersionInfo;
  RegHandle: HKEY;
  MapiDetectBuf: array[0..8] of Char;
  MapiDetectBufSize: Windows.DWORD;
  RegValueType: Windows.DWORD;
begin
  { first check wether MAPI is available on the system; this is done
    as described in the MS MAPI docs }

  OSVersionInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize := SizeOf(OSVersionInfo);
  GetVersionEx(OSVersionInfo);
  if (OSVersionInfo.dwMajorVersion > 3) or { NT 4.0 and later }
     { earlier than NT 3.51 }
     ((OSVersionInfo.dwMajorVersion = 3) and (OSVersionInfo.dwMinorVersion > 51)) then
  begin
    if RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                     'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Messaging Subsystem',
                     0, KEY_READ, RegHandle) <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
    begin
      exit;
    end;

    MAPIDetectBufSize := SizeOf(MAPIDetectBuf);
    if RegQueryValueEx( RegHandle, 'MAPI', nil, @RegValueType,
                        PByte(@MAPIDetectBuf), @MAPIDetectBufSize) <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
    begin
      exit;
    end;

    RegCloseKey(RegHandle);

    { "boolean" integer --> is == "1"? }
    if not ((MAPIDetectBuf[0] = '1') and (MAPIDetectBuf[1] = #0)) then
      exit;
  end
  else
    if GetProfileInt('Mail', 'MAPI', 0) = 0 then { 16 bit and NT 3.51 detection logic }
      Exit;

  OldErrorMode := SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS + SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX);
    DLLHandle := LoadLibrary(DLLName32); { start without .DLL attached }
  { OldErrorMode := } SetErrorMode(OldErrorMode);

  if DLLHandle = 0 then { got an error }
  begin
    OldErrorMode := SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS + SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX);
    try
      DLLHandle := LoadLibrary(DLLName32DLL);

      if DLLHandle = 0 then
      begin
        exit; { second attempt did not work out either }
      end;

    finally
      { OldErrorMode := } SetErrorMode(OldErrorMode);
    end;
  end;
  begin
    DllInitialized := true;

    @FnMapiFindNext :=    GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'MAPIFindNext');
    @FnMapiLogoff :=      GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'MAPILogoff');
    @FnMapiLogon :=       GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'MAPILogon');
    @FnMapiSendMail :=    GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'MAPISendMail');
    @FnMapiReadMail :=    GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'MAPIReadMail');
    @FnMapiDeleteMail :=  GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'MAPIDeleteMail');
    @FnMapiResolveName := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'MAPIResolveName');
    @FnMapiFreeBuffer :=  GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'MAPIFreeBuffer');
    @FnMapiAddress :=     GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'MAPIAddress');
    @FnMapiSaveMail :=    GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'MAPISaveMail');

    if    (@FnMapiAddress     = nil)
       or (@FnMapiFreeBuffer  = nil)
       or (@FnMapiResolveName = nil)
       or (@FnMapiDeleteMail  = nil)
       or (@FnMapiReadMail    = nil)
       or (@FnMapiSendMail    = nil)
       or (@FnMapiLogon       = nil)
       or (@FnMapiLogoff      = nil)
       or (@FnMapiFindNext    = nil)
       or (@FnMapiSaveMail    = nil) then
    begin
      raise EMAPIdllerror.Create(SMapiGetProcAdressFailed);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

**Relevant code from Email.pas**

```
destructor TEmail.Destroy;
begin
  ...
  try
    if hSession <> 0 then
      Logoff;
  except
  end;
end;
function TEmail.Logon: Integer;
const
  ProfileKey95 = 'Software\Microsoft\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles';
  ProfileKeyNT = 'Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles';
var
  LogonProfile : PChar;
  LogonPassword: PChar;

  ProfileKey   : PChar;

  Reg : TRegistry;
begin
  CheckMapi;
  Result := SUCCESS_SUCCESS;
  { Check if already logged in. }
  if hSession = 0 then
  begin
    if FUseDefProfile then
    begin
      Reg := TRegistry.Create;
      try
        { get platform (Win95/NT) dependent profile key                }
        {  code added by Ulrik Schoth schoth@krohne.mhs.compuserve.com }
        if Reg.KeyExists(ProfileKeyNT) then
        begin
          ProfileKey := ProfileKeyNT;
        end
        else
        begin
          ProfileKey := ProfileKey95;
        end;

        Reg.Rootkey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
        if Reg.OpenKey(ProfileKey, False) then
        begin
          try
            FProfile := Reg.Readstring('DefaultProfile');
          except
            FProfile := '';
          end;
        end;
      finally
        Reg.Free;
      end;
    end;

    LogonProfile := nil;
    LogonPassword := nil;

    try
      if Length(FProfile) > 0 then
      begin
        LogonProfile := StrPCopy(StrAlloc(Length(FProfile)+1), FProfile);
      end;

      if Length(FPassword) > 0 then
      begin
        LogonPassword := StrPCopy(StrAlloc(Length(FPassword)+1), FPassword);
      end;

      DoBeforeLogon;

      Result := MapiLogon(0, LogonProfile, LogonPassword, flLogonFlags, 0, @hSession);
      if Result <> SUCCESS_SUCCESS then
        Result := MapiLogon(0, nil, nil, flLogonFlags or MAPI_Logon_UI, 0, @hSession);

      if Result = SUCCESS_SUCCESS then
        DoAfterLogon
      else
        DoMapiError(Result);

    finally
      StrDispose(LogonProfile);
      StrDispose(LogonPassword);
    end;
  end;
end;

function TEmail.SendMailEx(DoSave: boolean): Integer;
var
  MapiMessage   : TMapiMessage;
  MapiRecipDesc : TMapiRecipDesc;
  MapiFileDesc  : TMapiFileDesc;
  lpRecipArray  : TlpRecipArray;
  lpAttachArray : TlpAttachArray;
  lpszPathname  : TlpszPathname;
  lpszFileName  : TlpszFileName;

  szSubject     : PChar;
  szText        : PChar;
  szMessageId   : PChar;
  szMessageType : PChar;

  Attachment    : SString;
  flFlags       : ULONG;
  flLogoff      : Boolean;

  i             : Integer;
  nRecipients   : Integer;
  nAttachments  : Integer;

begin
  CheckMapi;

  {make sure the cleanup does not free garbage }
  lpRecipArray  := nil;
  lpAttachArray := nil;

  flLogoff      := False;

  {check our built-in limits - which have effectively been removed }
  nRecipients := Frecip.Count + FCC.Count + FBCC.Count;
  if nRecipients > RECIP_MAX then
  begin
    Result := MAPI_E_TOO_MANY_RECIPIENTS;

    DoMapiError(Result);

    exit;
  end;

  nAttachments := FAttachment.Count;
  if nAttachments > ATTACH_MAX then
  begin
    Result := MAPI_E_TOO_MANY_FILES;

    DoMapiError(Result);

    exit;
  end;

  { begin the work }
  try

    flLogoff := (hSession = 0);

    { Logon to mail server if not already logged on. }

    if Logon <> SUCCESS_SUCCESS then
    begin
      Result := MAPI_E_LOGIN_FAILURE;

      DoMapiError(Result);

      exit;
    end;


    { Initialise MAPI structures and local arrays. }

    FillChar(MapiMessage,   SizeOf(TMapiMessage),   0);
    FillChar(MapiRecipDesc, SizeOf(TMapiRecipDesc), 0);
    FillChar(MapiFileDesc,  SizeOf(TMapiFileDesc),  0);

    lpRecipArray  := TlpRecipArray(StrAlloc(nRecipients*SizeOf(TMapiRecipDesc)));
    FillChar(lpRecipArray^, StrBufSize(PChar(lpRecipArray)), 0);

    lpAttachArray := TlpAttachArray(StrAlloc(nAttachments*SizeOf(TMapiFileDesc)));
    FillChar(lpAttachArray^, StrBufSize(PChar(lpAttachArray)), 0);

    { Fill in subject & message text. }

    szSubject      := nil;
    szText         := nil;
    szMessageId    := nil;
    szMessageType  := nil;

    try
      if Length(FSubject) > 0 then
      begin
        szSubject := StrAlloc(length(FSubject) + 1);
        StrPCopy(szSubject, FSubject);
      end;
      MapiMessage.lpszSubject  := szSubject;

      if Length(FText) > 0 then
      begin
        szText := StrAlloc(length(FText) + 1);
        StrPCopy(szText, FText);
      end;
      MapiMessage.lpszNoteText := szText;

      { for non-IPM messages }
      if Length(FMessageType) > 0 then
      begin
        szMessageType := StrAlloc(Length(FMessageType) + 1);
        StrPCopy(szMessageType, FMessageType);
      end;
      MapiMessage.lpszMessageType := szMessageType;

      if FpLongText <> nil then
        MapiMessage.lpszNoteText := FpLongText;

      { check and fill in recipients if any}
      nRecipients := 0;
      ListToRecipArray(FRecip, MAPI_TO,  lpRecipArray, nRecipients);
      ListToRecipArray(FCC,    MAPI_CC,  lpRecipArray, nRecipients);
      ListToRecipArray(FBcc,   MAPI_BCC, lpRecipArray, nRecipients);


      MapiMessage.nRecipCount := nRecipients;

      flFlags := 0; { Don't display MAPI Dialog if recipient specified. }

        MapiMessage.lpRecips := @lpRecipArray^;

      { Process file attachments. }

      nAttachments := 0;

      for i := 0 to (Fattachment.Count - 1) do
      begin
        Attachment := CheckAttachment(Fattachment.Strings[i]);
        if Length(Attachment) = 0 then
        begin
          Result := MAPI_E_ATTACHMENT_NOT_FOUND;

          DoMapiError(Result);

          exit;
        end;
        lpAttachArray^[i].nPosition    := Integer($FFFFFFFF);  {Top of message. }
        lpszPathname                   := new(TlpszPathname);
        lpAttachArray^[i].lpszPathName := StrPcopy(lpszPathname^, Attachment);


      { begin code added by MJK }
        lpszFileName                   := new(TlpszFileName);

        { truncate attachment filename if desired }
        if FTruncAttFN then
        begin
          { truncate }
          lpAttachArray^[i].lpszFileName :=
            StrPCopy(lpszFileName^, TruncAttachmentFN(ExtractFileName(Attachment)))
        end
        else
        begin
          { leave alone }
          lpAttachArray^[i].lpszFileName :=
            StrPCopy(lpszFileName^, ExtractFileName(Attachment));
        end;
      {end code added by MJK}

        Inc(nAttachments);
      end;

      MapiMessage.nFileCount := nAttachments;
      if nAttachments > 0 then
      begin
        MapiMessage.lpFiles := @lpAttachArray^;
      end
      else
      begin
        MapiMessage.lpFiles := nil;
      end;

      { receipt requested ? }
      if FAcknowledge then
        MapiMessage.flFlags := MapiMessage.flFlags or MAPI_RECEIPT_REQUESTED;

      { finally send the email message }

      DoBeforeSendMail;

      Result := MapiSendMail(hSession, 0, @MapiMessage, flFlags, 0);
      if Result = SUCCESS_SUCCESS then
        DoAfterSendMail
      else
        DoMapiError(Result);


    finally
      StrDispose(szSubject);
      StrDispose(szText);
      StrDispose(szMessageID);
      StrDispose(szMessageType);
    end;

  finally
    { dispose of the recipient & CC name strings }
    if Assigned(lpRecipArray) then
      for i := 0 to (nRecipients - 1) do
      begin
        if Assigned(lpRecipArray^[i].lpszName) then
          Dispose(lpRecipArray^[i].lpszName);

        if Assigned(lpRecipArray^[i].lpszAddress) then
          Dispose(lpRecipArray^[i].lpszAddress);
      end;

    { dispose of the recipient/CC/BCC array }
    StrDispose(PChar(lpRecipArray));

    { dispose of the attachment file name strings }
    if Assigned(lpAttachArray) then
      for i := 0 to (nAttachments - 1) do
      begin
        Dispose(lpAttachArray^[i].lpszPathname);
        Dispose(lpAttachArray^[i].lpszFileName);
      end;

    { dispose of the attachment array }
    StrDispose(PChar(lpAttachArray));

    { Auto logoff, if no session was active. }
    if flLogoff = True then
      Logoff;
  end;

end;
```

*ps. I can't post the dump, it's 4GB but feel free to ask any additional required details I might have left out*

Comment: It would seem that this freeware component was born in the age of Win3.1 and hasn't seen any development in the past 16 years... you might rather consider moving to a more modern solution.

Comment: @J - The component is old but the culprit I believe is MSMAPI32.dll/EMSMDB32.dll. The age of the component as such doesn't matter, a new component would still have to use mapilogon, mapisendmail and mapilogof from MSMAPI32.dll.

Comment: @whosrdaddy - My primary suspect is the `EMSMDB32.dll`. I assume it starts a new thread to do the registration and whatnot. The error is not in my code but perhaps by initializing the MAPI session in another way, the `EMSMDB32` doesn't need to register and doesn't result in a deadlock. *(or perhaps even by changing an Exchange parameter)*

Comment: I seriously doubt that those DLLs are the problem - they are extremely mature and have been in heavy use for years.  I would have a look at `email32.pas` that provides the `TEmail` component - surely the calling code is at fault here.

Comment: @J - The `CS` owned by my main thread isn't created by our code, I assume its created by `EMSMDB32`. The second thread isn't created by our code either, I assume it's also created by EMSMDB32 *(entry point certainly seems to confirm that)*. I have already looked over the code in `email32.pas` and couldn't find anything suspicious. I'll post some relevant code if you wait a bit *(at home now, have to remote in)*

Comment: You don't have to own the CS to do something illegal - corrupt a session, etc. Who knows, it could also be a DLL versioning conflict between whatever versions of `MAPI32.DLL` have changed since 1998.  MSDN says `The use of this function is discouraged. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of Windows.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296726%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @J-I have added the code that initializes, logs on, sends and logs of from MAPI. I for one hope you are right it's an error in our code. We can fix *our* code :)

Comment: Tx for the link but following that, it seems that the [entire use of Simple MAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296734(v=vs.85).aspx) is discouraged. If that's so, do you know what alternatives we have?

Comment: Generally you would use either Extended MAPI or Outlook Object Model to do this sort of thing now.

Comment: It's very unlikely that the app is going to be rewritten but rather it being phased out. If you know any pointers that migth lead to a solution for the given app, be it either exchange configuration, client setup or our custom code, by all means, shoot <g>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the opportunity to get the dump analyzed by a friendly party.

**Conclusions are** *(my interpretation)*

- This could be a bug in `EMSMDB32.dll` but the code is so old that there's more than likely not any support or intention to fix it.
- The offset in `EMSMDB32!EcUnregisterPushNotification+0x11db3` is so large that it's likely not executing the `EcUnregisterPushNotification` method. What method instead might be executing could not be determined.

**Possible solutions**

As it's impossible for us to fix the bug *(assuming it is a bug)*, following workarounds would work in our case

- Restart the service every x minutes.
- Group the mails to send by profile and send as batch instead of logging on/off for each mail.
- Start a secondary thread to watch the main thread and have it restart the service if a deadlock is detected.